# Mapping java.util.Optional in Hibernate 4.x or 5.x

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How do I map a field of type java.util.Optional? I tried  `@Converter` annotation and `AttributeConverter`,

```
@Converter
public class OptionalConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<Optional<T>, T>{
    @Override
    public T convertToDatabaseColumn(Optional<T> attribute) {
        return attribute.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> convertToEntityAttribute(T dbData) {
        return Optional.of(dbData);
    }
}
```

But it didn't go as planned. Any pointers or `Optional` is not supported in Hibernate at all? Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to force the use of the converter using

```
// Entity field
@Convert(converter = OptionalConverter.class)
private Optional<Foo> foo;
```

or if that doesn’t help, implement a converter for the specific `Optional` type:

```
@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class OptionalFooConverter
    extends OptionalConverter<Foo>
    implements AttributeConverter<Optional<Foo>, Foo> { // this line is necessary when using EclipseLink
    @Override
    public Foo convertToDatabaseColumn(Optional<Foo> attribute) {
        return attribute.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Foo> convertToEntityAttribute(Foo dbData) {
        return Optional.of(dbData);
    }
}

// Entity field
@Convert(converter = OptionalFooConverter.class)
private Optional<Foo> foo;
```

As there are other drawbacks regarding `Optional` fields in entity classes (for example, `@NotNull` may not work as intended), you could also have the field itself as a regular nullable (non-`Optional`) type and do the conversion in the getter and setter.